# Incompatible types on assignment - C program for system date

Tags: c, types

I'm trying to parse the system date by calling struct tm and getting the current time before parsing into separate day, month, year. Here is my code at hte moment:

```
/* Parses a system date structure 'system_date' into a structure date 'parsed_date'.*/
int parse_system_date(struct tm system_date, date * parsed_date) {
     time_t ts;
     struct tm t;

     ts = time(NULL);
     t = localtime(&ts);

     /* scan the year, month and year from the input string*/ 
     //printf("Current Date: %d/%d/%d\n",
         // current_time->tm_mday, current_time->tm_mon + 1, current_time->tm_year + 1900);

     const int ret = sscanf(system_date, "%d/%d/%d",
            &parsed_date->(tm_mday),
            &parsed_date->(tm_month + 1),
            &parsed_date->(tm_year + 1900));
     return ret;

}
```

And it's being called from the main by:

```
struct tm t;
char system_date[20];

fgets(system_date, 20, stdin); 
    parse_system_date(system_date, &t);
    printf("Today's date is: %s\ndd = %d, mm = %d, yy = %d\n", system_date, t.tm_mday, t.tm_mon, t.tm_year);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
date.h:30: error: incompatible types in assignment
```

In the line:

```
t = localtime(&ts);
```

And:

```
date.h:39: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘sscanf’
```

for the line:

```
&parsed_date->(tm_mday).
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help! Just to note: I'm a beginner programmer but trying to immerse myself entirely as I just started  PhD that deals mainly in programming so I'm a total newbie.

Answer (score 2):

The function `localtime` is [**documented**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) to return a `struct tm*`  (that is, a Pointer to a Structure).

You are trying to assign that to variable `t`, which has type `struct tm` (note: no pointer in there).

You cannot assign a pointer to a non-pointer.

I recommend changing to:

```
int parse_system_date(struct tm system_date, date * parsed_date) {
     struct tm* pt;
     [....]
     pt = localtime(&ts);
```

---

Now I'll leave it up to you to look up the documentation of `sscanf`, and YOU tell US what param #1 to `sscanf` should be, and what you are actually passing.

Answer (score 0):

`system_date` is `char *` in `main` and `struct tm system_date` in the function call.
Change the function call to

```
int parse_system_date(char *system_date, date * parsed_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

As `man localtime` states:

> struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timep);

Your `t` in `t = localtime(&ts)` is a `struct tm` not `struct tm*`, and `localtime` returns a pointer.

For second thing you didn't really show us how does `parsed_date` look (no definition of `date` structure). Also `system_date` is a `struct tm` then why would you expect it would be taken as `const char*` in `sscanf`?

Answer (score 0):

A working solution for you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Parses a system date structure 'system_date' into a structure date 'parsed_date'.*/
void parse_system_date(char* system_date, struct tm **parsed_date) {
     time_t ts;

     int ret;
     int year;
     int month;
     int day;

     ts = time(NULL);
     *parsed_date = localtime(&ts);

     sscanf(system_date,"%d/%d/%d",&day,&month,&year);
     (*parsed_date)->tm_mday = day;
     (*parsed_date)->tm_mon = month + 1;
     (*parsed_date)->tm_year = year + 1900;

}

int main(){

   struct tm* t;
   char system_date[20]={'\0'};

   fgets(system_date, 20, stdin);
   parse_system_date(system_date, &t);
   printf("Today's date is: %s\ndd = %d, mm = %d, yy = %d\n", system_date, t->tm_mday, t->tm_mon, t->tm_year);

return 0;
}
```

Input : 11/03/2014

Output: Today's date is: 11/03/2014

dd = 11, mm = 4, yy = 3914

I modified your code to get a meaningful output but I did not understand the requirement of your program. Because you have few unused variables and operations like,

```
 time_t ts;                                               
 struct tm t;

 ts = time(NULL);
 t = localtime(&ts);
```

and function signature also wrong.

Answer (score -2):

localtime returns a pointer to the struct:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/

Comment: It would be nice not to give answer ONLY with link.

Comment: Since the poster is new to programming it seems important that they become familiar with this website

Comment: Well, then point them to it. But dont' give only link in an answer. What if this site will disappear in a meantime? Your answer will be useless. Also it's a c++ reference site, so it's not really related.

Comment: I didn't ONLY post a link - I first mentioned that localtime returns a pointer, which is what the poster's problem was. I don't see the need to mark this answer down